# How to receive notifications irrespective of which controller the user is on in Swift + Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, notifications

I am using Swift and Firebase Firestore. Regardless of on which view controller the user is on, I want him to receive in app notifications (when his friend request was denied or when he receives a message, for instance).

The option that I have in mind is using snapshotlisteners in the AppDelegate but this does not seem to be very efficient to me, since these snapshotlisteners would not be deinitialized.

I've thought about using push notifications but this would not work, since the user may disable push notifications. Or is there any way to achieve this functionality with push notifications?

Comment: You should use push notifications. If the notification is received while your app is in the foreground, then it is your app's responsibility to display it somehow when the notification information is delivered to your notification center delegate. It is not affected by the user's notification  settings. If the notification is received while your app is not in the foreground, then yes, the user may not see the notification, but that is their decision. You can also check for updated documents when your app returns to the foreground to provide information

Comment: My aim is to update some singletons in the app with the data of these push notifications. Then my question would be: If the app is in the background, the user disabled notifications, user receives some text messages while the app is in the background, user opens the app - will the singletons be updated by the push notifications (that were sent while the app was in the background) once the app is in the foreground again?

Comment: The notifications won't be delivered when your app is opened. The notifications were already delivered, but the user chose not to display them. Even if they were displayed, your app won't receive any information about them unless the user taps on one. Your app needs to fetch any updated documents.  Notifying the user and keeping your app updated are separate things.

Comment: You need to structure your Firestore data so that you don't need to monitor too many documents. For example, a single property on their user document that indicates the last time that there was a friend update. You can then check this date and know whether you need to examine the friends collection looking for more changes.  Documents in the friends collection should also have updatedAt time stamps so you can identify which ones hav changed.

Comment: I appreciate your input. I think my question is more like - What is the best way to keep my app updated? I have 4 view controllers. If bob rejects tom's friend request, I want all 4 of Tom's view controllers to know this, without having Tom to visit a specific view controller in order to know that. Should I just add snapshotlisteners to all view controllers? I thought there might be a better approach

Comment: You should have a shared model object, but also, I wouldn't have any of the view controllers responsible for showing the notification. I would have another class that presents a "toast" or similar over the current view controller. The view controller itself doesn't need to know about this. You can just get the current window

Comment: Sorry I am being dumb. I do not want all view controllers to know about the change in the database, I want a specific singleton class to adjust to the change in the database. If Bob rejects Tom's friend request, I want Tom's singleton class that is responsible for friend requests to remove the friend request. Right now, I have this functionality happen in a specific VC, but Tom has to visit the VC first for the singleton to update according to the change in the database. Does that make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255294/discussion-between-paulw11-and-ozgun).